does an exact sequence of filtered complexes induce an exact sequence of spectral sequences
Let $(A_i, d_i, F_i)$ be a filtered differential complex (with bounded filtration) for $i=1,2,3$. Assume we have filtered chain maps $i:A_1\to A_2$ and $j:A_2\to A_3$ such that
$$0\to A_1 \overset{i}{\longrightarrow} A_2 \overset{j}{\longrightarrow} A_3 \to 0 $$
is exact.
Let $E_{i,\infty}^{p,q}$ be the $\infty$ page of the spectral sequence associated to the filtered differential complex $(A_i, d_i, F_i)$. Is it true that we have an exact sequence
$$0\to E_{1,\infty}^{p,q} \overset{?}{\longrightarrow}  E_{2,\infty}^{p,q} \overset{?}{\longrightarrow}  E_{3,\infty}^{p,q} \to 0 $$

Some related discussion on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455843/spectral-sequences-and-short-exact-sequences

Thanks, I was looking at linked article https://www.mn.uio.no/math/personer/vit/rognes/papers/highfix.pdf . I have no idea whats a cofiber sequence sequence of filtered spectra is. The thing is that if I understand correctly the proof of proposition 5.4, what I realy need is for the mapr $Z^r A_2\to Z^r A_3$ to be surjective?
